# linear algebra libraries for clusters

Tags: math, cluster-computing

I need to develop applications doing linear algebra + eigenvalue + linear equation solutions over a cluster of pcs ( I have a lot of machines available).

I discovered Scalapack libraries but they seem to me developed long time ago.

Do you know if these are other libs available that I should learn doing math & linear algebra in a cluster?

My language is C++ and off course I am newbie to this topic.

Comment: You should specify if you are performing dense or sparse linear algebra, as the packages are specialized and differ greatly.

Comment: Hi . Most probably they will be dense matrix computation.
Do you have any suggestions also for Partial Differential Equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of problem you are mentionning are very different and I doubt there is a single library that would do everything efficiently. Some libraries may also be suited more specifically for linear algebra problems rising from specific applications (like finite elements problems).

Concerning libraries, I have never used Scalapack, but remember that in this field, old does not necessarily means bad. Here are a few other picks you can choose from:

- [PETSc](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-as/) : linear solvers
- [SLEPc](http://www.grycap.upv.es/slepc/) : eigenvalue solvers
- [MUMPS](http://graal.ens-lyon.fr/MUMPS/) and [SuperLU](http://crd.lbl.gov/~xiaoye/SuperLU/): linear solvers

Of course,...have a look at the [netlib](http://www.netlib.org/liblist.html) repository, you might find interesting things, including some libraries on which the above links rely.

Finally, about the language, remember that efficiency will also depend on the use of the appropriate libraries: Blas ,Atlas, Lapack,... which are most probably written in "some language other than C++" and you'll just have to call them with the appropriate wrapper.

Comment: Hi Adrien Thanks for your nice resposne!
Do you have any suggestions also for Partial Differential Equations?
I read that PETSc might be a good solution..have you ever used it?
Thaks

Comment: Never used Petsc personally, but I heard its quite nice.